# Is Eye Contact Required to Create a Connection?

Tags: sense8

In Sense8 we see that as a cluster becomes accustomed to the others, communication is fast, easy, and generally reliable.  We also see that those outside of the cluster (Jonas, Whispers, the Icelandic woman) can visit with sensates, though they cannot share.

We know that Whispers cannot visit a sensate unless he first makes eye contact with them at some point.  And Jonas only visits Nomi and Will, possibly only because he had physical contact with only those two sensates.  Lastly, the Icelandic woman only visits with Riley, though we are not necessarily shown any previous physical contact, we do see that:

> At the symphony, when the cluster is experiencing their birth memories, it does look like the Icelandic woman is present at Riley's birth.  However, the woman I think is the Icelandic woman is not properly seen, so it might be someone else.

So, my question is, is eye contact required to create a sensate connection outside of a cluster?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You're answering the 'do you need eye contact' question by including the Whispers and Icelandic woman examples.  Jonas explicitly explains this ability as well.

Comment: @Keen Updated for clarity.  While it is known that Whispers needs eye contact, I do not recall that being explicitly stated for *all* sensates.  If you have quotes handy that do state this explicitly, please put those in an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In S1E4, just before minute 31, Jonas says to Gorski, "Angel called it 'visiting'. Members of a cluster do it instinctively, and others, like us, outside the cluster can visit *if they've made visual contact*. Eye to eye."

And when we support this explanation of the connection with what we know about Whispers requiring eye contact to connect with Gorski, I think we can say yes, eye contact is required.